# How to delete File in c#

Tags: c#

Please tell me why file.Delete(gpath) is not working?

i will be very thankful to you :) If there is any error on this code then tell about that error.This code can be wrong so please tell me.

```
        string gpath;

        string path=@"c:\Users\Adam\Desktop\";

        string name="file";

        string f="";

        int i=0;

        string ext=".txt";

        while(File.Exists(path + name + f + ext))
        {
            i++;

            f = i.ToString();
        }

        gpath = path + name + f + ext;

        button2.Enabled = true;

        File.Create(gpath);

        File.Delete(gpath);//why there is an Error??
```

Comment: Uhm, what error?

Comment: I suppose you could do `File.Create(gpath).Close();`  Any reason you are creating and deleting a file immediately?

Comment: thanks Kevin DiTragila :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) returns a `FileStream` which you haven't disposed of, so there's an open handle to the file. When you try and delete a file with that has a handle attached to it, you'll get an error saying that the file is in use.

I don't know why you're trying to delete the file straight after creating it so if you explain what you're ultimately attempting to do, there's likely a better way of going about it.

Comment: I am beginner in c# that's y i am asking this question to you...Thanks alot my brother :)

Comment: @user2642928 - No problem, happy to help :) I'm just saying if there's something in particular you're trying to do, I can try and show you a good way of doing it.